# Why is text on a UICollectionViewCell disappearing when tapped on?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`. It is filled with cells which include an image view and a label.

When one taps on a cell the text just disappears. **How can I stop this from happening?**

**Extra information:**

The collection view is within a container connected to a baseVC.

Cells and most of their content are added in its xib file. Everything shows up correctly. Expect when tapping, where text disappears and then reappears.

Also note that the label does not disappear, only the text.

The custom text is added when calling a cells: `func setup(profImage: String, contentView: String, titleLabel: String, subtitleLabel: String)` and even when disabling the text from being added the default labels still disappear on tap.

Comment: Could you make a repo or something that has a sample xcode project?

Comment: I included what I could here: https://github.com/makinggainz/CollectionViewCode @codeherk

Comment: I attempted to create a new xcode project and import code from the link you provided. It generated 15 errors. The, `CollectionViewCellP1` is used in `P1BottomSheetViewController`'s extension and that is an undeclared type. It would really help if you can start a sample xcode project with those custom classes in use.

Comment: Too big of a project to share @codeherk

Comment: At least provide the didSelectCell method code? Or if its a button or something within the cell, then the cell interaction code

Comment: See edit.......@SeanLintern

Comment: Could you try disabling user Interaction?

Comment: I have tried isUserInteractionEnabled = false and the problem persisted.

Comment: @Outsider can you show us your `cell.setup()` method?

Comment: Please provide some screenshots from before and after tapping.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini see update

Comment: for a quick fix you can call , `deselectMethod` of `collectionView` inside `collectionViewDidSelectItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure the label is added to the `contentView` of the cell and not just the "top-most" view of the cell. Maybe the way the `xib` is setup is not right. Make sure it is `UICollectionViewCell` in the xib etc. You could also post pictures of how you have setup the `xib`.

Also, to debug, I would remove any code that deals with the cell that is not revolved around the label (for example, remove the animations until you fixed the bug). That will allow you to zone in on the issue. Or, another way, just begin from scratch and re-create the cell (with only the label). Getting a label to display is not rocket science, but you can make it rocket science if you do not build what is going on step-by-step.

Another potential issue is layout. Is the layout done right? And maybe it breaks (for some reason) when you highlight.

Comment: So I tested something new, I added a label to the cell and then ran and when tapping that label does not disappear. I also checked and made sure it was not due to constraints. The only difference between that label and the text is that the text is changed when the reloadData() is called

Comment: @Outsider Then I would build on what you got working. Delete all the views. Get that one label working with text. Test it. Then second label. Test it. Then add the images. Test it. It's a slim chance that it's some unknown iOS bug (people display labels on cells all the time when building apps), it's probably something silly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using UILabel's highlighted text color property:

> The highlight color applied to the label’s text.
>
> @property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *highlightedTextColor;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the text after the animation is completed ?

```
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let thumbnail = postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].thumbnail!
            let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: postArray[indexPath.row].media[0].postTimeStamp!, isItForP3: false).getDate!

    UIView.animatewithDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
            cell!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
      if finished {
        cell.setup(profImage: "\(self.postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrlString!)", contentView: thumbnail, titleLabel: postArray[indexPath.item].user.username!, subtitleLabel: date)
      }  
    })
```

There's probably a better way to do this, though.

Comment: But I would like the text to be visible at all times. Additionally, berfore I ever added this animation, this weird behaviore was present

Comment: mmm is there any other way you can do the same animation?  Seems just weird to transform the whole cell (UICollectionViewCell), what about adding a container view on the cell and adding a function to create the same animation on that view, instead of the superview?

Comment: Why does it seem weird? is it not good practice? Anyway, if you believe it is related I do not think that's the case because before I had even included an animation this was an issue.

Comment: @Outsider Are you recycling the cell ? I would advice adding a method to your view, like drawAsPlaceholder() (in which you reset every value - label - image - etc), and then calling it in your setup method